# How to get the event of a directive in a dynamic component when @HostDirective() is set?

Tags: angular

Here is a code to dynamically create a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic',
  template: `{{ message }}`,
  standalone: true,
  hostDirectives: [
    {
      directive: OneDirective,
      outputs: ['change: messageChange'],
    },
  ],
})
export class DynamicComponent {
  @Input() message: string;

  @Output() messageChange = new EventEmitter();

  // How to get the change event in the current component?
}
```

OneDirective

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'one-driective',
  exportAs: '[oneDirective]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class OneDirective {
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.change.emit('emit event');
  }
}
```

OneComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  template: `<ng-template #container></ng-template>`,
  standalone: true,
})
export class OneComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const component = this.container.createComponent(DynamicComponent);
    component.setInput('message', 'help me');
    // How to get the change event in the current component?
    component.instance.messageChange.subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(111);
      console.log(x);
    });
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dn9f1s?file=src/one.component.ts

I'm expecting to get events for a directive on a component that uses HostDirective , or externally where the component is dynamically created!
I really need your help. Thank you

Comment: `this.messageChange.subscribe` should work

Comment: I tried it, and I can’t receive the value by subscribing myself. I didn’t understand what you meant. Please take a look at the latest code again.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dn9f1s?file=src/dynamic.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Finally, instructions are again injected into the dynamic component to listen for change

```js
@Component({
  selector: ...,
  template: ...,
  standalone: true,
  hostDirectives: [OneDirective],
})
export class DynamicComponent {

  ...
  constructor(private oneDirective: OneDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Currently the interaction is in the form of injection
    this.oneDirective.change.subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(222, x);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems remapping for outputs in directive is only ment for template events usage `(messageChange)="..."`. at least unltill something like `.setInput` functionality analog for outputs appears in angular. If you want to still remap your output for usage like you are trying to do in the example I would suggest doing this

```
class DynamicComponent {
  messageChange = this.oneDirective.change;
```

or even

```
class DynamicComponent {
  messageChange = inject(OneDirective).change;
```

if you want to eliminate the constructor.

Another point not related to the question is how you use ngAfterViewInit hook. it happends after the change detection is done on the component, and that is why you had to use `.detectChanges()` after something was updated. in most cases static queries

```
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
```

can be used. when the query is static - you can access the container in ngOnInit and follow the root to leaves change detection without any hacks

Comment: Yeah, great! I ended up re-injecting the instruction so that I could interact with it.
Thank you for your help